# Autofix or shortcut for prettier issues in VS Code React Native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using Visual Studio Code with a React Native project. ESLint is used to check the stuff specified in the `.prettierrc.js`. 
When something isn't correct I get a hint like this:

[image]

Instead of getting these notifications and right clicking on them, selecting `Fix this prettier/prettier problem`, I want the problems to be fixed either automatically or using a shortcut combination. How can I configure that? I am currently using pure JavaScript, no Typescript.

Answer (score 20):

Edit/create `.vscode/settings.json` so it will contain

```
{
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
}
```

Fixes issues on save.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for @jonrsharpe! Just want to add my few cents.

1. Go to **settings.json** file:

   - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
   - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
   - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`
2. Add there:

```
 {
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
     "source.fixAll.eslint": true
   },
 }
```

3. Restart VSCode

Enjoy coding!))

**UPDATE**

While on Mac the solution above worked for me, on Windows to make it works I had to add following to **settings.json** :

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
        "source.fixAll": true
      },
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true
```

Answer (score 0):

In **.eslintrc.js** file need to add this

```
rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
 },
```

the complete file looks like this:

```
module.exports = { 
  root: true, 
  extends: '@react-native', 
  rules: { 
    'prettier/prettier': 0,  
  }, 
  'prettier/prettier': 0, 
};
```

---